# Dealing with multiple SQL queries within single find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please note that I understand I could do the following in a single SQL query that's not the point of the question however... I'm more curious about how rails deals with multiple queries.

Let's say I have a Movies model with attributes such as title, director, id, star, release date, etc.

Now I have @Movies = find_by_sql("select * from movies where genre='Action';select * from movies where genre='Comedy';")

And I iterate through it on the view. However only the first query results seem to be contained in the answer. Just curious about how this works.

Thanks

Comment: i am not able to run multiple queries how can i do that??

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
@Movies = find_by_sql("select * from movies where genre='Action' or genre='Comedy';")
```

Edit: this is maybe what you're refering to with the single query.

Another way to do it is

```
find_by_genre('Action') << find_by_genre('Comedy')
```

Comment: Yeah this was what I was referring to as a single query. Not really interested in getting the query results I want more interested in how rails deals with it.

Comment: I think "the rails way" would be the second one: fetch result for each category and return concatenated arrays. If you want only one DB trip, I think you'll have to use the single query (or a variation).

Answer (score 0):

Try the `UNION SELECT...` sql query...

Also, LOL cs142?

Comment: Yes CS142 and yes union select is the correct way to do it. Since the multiple query was my first attempt though I am still curious about how Rails handles multiple queries with the find_by_sql command. Looks like it just stops after the first query?